# efficient farming

Tags: code-golf

## Introduction

A farmer needs help calculating the least time it will take him to pick his fruit each day.

## Challenge

- This farmer has `X` orchards.
- Each orchard has `Y` fruits in it. If the orchard has no fruits, then it will contain the string "none".
- The farmer has a list, this list contains the fruit he must pick.
- The farmer will only go down the list **in order**
- You must calculate how long it will take the farmer to pick his fruit on each day.

#### More on the orchards

- All of the orchards are in a line.
- Each orchard is exactly `1` unit away from the next and previous one.
- The farmer can go up and down the line, but may not jump from one orchard to another

## Input and Output

You will receive an input in the following format:

```
X
*string*
*string*
*string* *string* *string* *string*
*string*
//ect.
Y
*string* *string*
*string* *string*
*string* *string*
*string* *string*
//ect.
```

`X` is the number of orchards

- Everything after `X` and before `Y` is an orchard containing a/some string(s), each string is a different fruit in that orchard.

`Y` is the number of days that the farmer must gather fruit.

- Each day consists of two strings that are different fruits.
- You must find what orchard these strings are in and calculate the difference.

#### Input Rules:

1. Each fruit name string will be one word with **no spaces**

#### Real Example

Still confused? Maybe this will clear it up:

Input

```
6 

none

apple

orange pear pear

none

orange lemon pumpkin

pumpkin lettuce flowers peas

4

peas lettuce 

apple orange 

apple pumpkin 

flowers orange
```

output: `[ 0, 1, 3, 1 ]`

#### Explanation

Input:

- `6` the number of orchards
- A set of `6` orchards containing fruit, each orchard on a new line.
- `4` the number of days on the farmers list.
- A set of `4` fruits to compare, each pair of fruits is on a new line.

Output:

- Output an array of the differences between each set of fruits.
- The difference between peas and lettuce is `0`, because they are in the same orchard.
- The difference between apples and oranges is `1` because they are one orchard apart.
- The difference between apples and pumpkins is `3` Because they are three orchards apart.
- The difference between flowers and oranges is `1` because they are one orchard apart.

---

Annotated input/output

```
6 orchards 

a none

b apple

c orange pear pear

d none

e orange lemon pumpkin

f pumpkin lettuce flowers peas

--

4 fruits

peas lettuce 0

apple orange 1

apple pumpkin 3

flower orange 1

--

output: [ 0, 1, 3, 1 ]
```

## How To Win

Shortest code in bytes wins.

## Rules

- [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so shortest solution in bytes wins
- [Standard Loopholes Apply](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default)
- The [meta definition of randomness](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1325/42649) applies
- You may use functions as well as programs

## Disclamer

I submitted this question to the sandbox, but I did not get any feedback on it, so feel free to edit as you see needed.

Comment: -1 No objective winning criteria

Comment: Good thing this went through the sandbox so this user could be informed about this before they lost rep for it. /S

Comment: You should ad the code-gold tag if this is a code-golf challenge

Comment: `Create a script/function that completes the challenge. The community will decide what script/function is best.` Does this mean it's a [tag:popularity-contest]?

Comment: its not code-golf. sorry my bad, I added a how to win part

Comment: Then you need to say that it's code golf. The way the challenge reads now, I think most people would assume popularity-contest

Comment: popularity contest sounds right. I just added that

Comment: Be warned that popularity contests are often closed, as they rarely have objective winning criteria.

Comment: That's a *terrible* use of popularity contest, tbh. Popularity Contest should only be used when another victory criterion is impossible to apply.

Comment: I *highly advise* making this code golf.

Comment: ok, I will make it code-golf then if that seems to be what most people think is best

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. This is now code-golf

Comment: If I was to go the function approach, would the input be one big string which has lines separated by newlines? or would the input be the lines as a string array/list?
Also, can a fruit name contain numbers? or just letters?

Comment: Yes, the input would be one big string with newlines.

Comment: Your explanation of the challenge is *really* confusing.  I was able to piece together what was being asked by the example test case, but users should be clear on the challenge just from the spec.  I would recommend rewriting the task.  I think one of the more confusing parts is the use of `X` and `Y` to refer to multiple different things,  however I'm not entirely sure if this is even the case.

Answer (score 2):

## 176 bytes, Python 3

```
def p(a):l=[b.split()for b in a.split('\n')];X=int(l[0][0]);return[min(y-x for y in range(X)for x in range(y+1)if z[0]in l[x+1]+l[y+1]and z[1]in l[x+1]+l[y+1])for z in l[X+2:]]
```

This can be called by passing in the entire content as a string

```
p("""6
none
apple
orange pear pear
none
orange lemon pumpkin
pumpkin lettuce flowers peas
4
peas lettuce
apple orange
apple pumpkin
flowers orange""")
```

Ungolfed solution

```
def problem(a):
    # this will split on new line, and split each individual line into it's own list
    lines=[b.split()for b in a.split('\n')]
    # get the number of orchards
    X=int(lines[0][0])
    return[
        # get the minimum of all possible differences
        min(y-x # subtract y and x to get the difference
            for y in range(X) # for each orchard, y
                for x in range(y+1) # and each orchard up to y inclusive, x
                    if z[0] in lines[x+1]+lines[y+1] and z[1] in lines[x+1]+lines[y+1]) # if both fruits exist the x and y orchards
        # for every day (z is a list containing 2 fruits as string)
        for z in lines[X+2:]
    ]
```

Comment: 153 bytes: `def p(a):l=[*map(str.split,a.split('\n'))];X=int(l[0][0]);return[min(y-x for y in range(X)for x in range(y+1)if{*z}<=set(l[x+1]+l[y+1]))for z in l[X+2:]]`

Answer (score 0):

## Java 10, <s>307</s> <s>298</s> <s>288</s> <s>280</s> <s>273</s> 271 bytes

```java
s->{String[]a=s.split("\\d"),o=a[1].split("\n"),f=a[2].split("\n");int r[]=new int[f.length-1],q=-2,d,i,j,z;for(var p:f)if(++q>=0)for(z=d=o.length,i=0;++i<d;)for(j=0;o[i].contains((f=p.split(" "))[0])&++j<z;)r[q]=d=o[j].contains(f[1])?Math.min(i>j?i-j:j-i,d):d;return r;}
```

-19 bytes thanks to *@ceilingcat*.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##VVLLbuQgELzvV7R8WIH80CRa7WEcJtoPSC452j6wNp5A7MYDeKJMNN8@235FWQljuorqbgqMPMvUNG@3upPew5PU@PkDQGNQrpW1gucpnIGigpq9BKfxCJ7nBF/po@GDDLqGZ0AQcPPp4XPZVVRS@MwPnQ4sKssm4okVsrirvjAkqCXo/j8op2Lgikqgep8Lt1mn8Bhe07sqOYn0PmkSnZjkkrfWsbN0MOxbrlsWx6eD2PEJvYhG2FWWaLHL41g/NPnMGQptoausthjowJ6xVgxbBxBxXuwq/jOOzcMl5644VVOywnwTtHQK/vgkw2vWa2T6YB51avYm1UnD903uVBgdgsuvt3wxaRj/dmTS6tXZ6gZ6SsU2q0DyxemXDx9Un9kxZANRoUNm6JKyMegu@@Oc/PBZsIuMYVazWQUQ/S4RLaoS5TB09LNO4lHBoCaDaNroFe9Ub5Ha6oc3jSWuC4JDGOne286@K@cnpS/xF22gxcauNWBJtUVfuTbtQkdzg5yvT@Z6@wc)

```java
s->{                           // Method with String parameter & integer-array return
  String[]a=s.split("\\d"),    //  Split the input on numbers
          o=a[1].split("\n"),  //  List of orchards
          f=a[2].split("\n");  //  List of pairs (later on reused for individual pair of fruits)
  int r[]=new int[f.length-1], //  Result integer-array
      q=-2,d,i,j,z;            //  Some temp integers
  for(var p:f)                 //  Loop `p` over the pairs:
    if(++q>=0){                //   If this isn't the first iteration of the pair-loop
                               //   (the first item is always empty after `.split("\\d")`)
      for(z=d=o.length,i=0;++i<d;)
                               //    Inner loop `i` over the orchards:
        for(j=0;o[i].contains((f=p.split(" "))[0])
                               //     If the current orchard contains the first fruit of the pair:
                &++j<z;)       //      Inner loop `j` over the orchards again:
          r[q]=                //       Add the following to the resulting array:
               d=o[j].contains(f[1])?
                               //       If the current orchard contains the second fruit of the pair:
                 Math.min(     //        Take the minimum of:
                   i>j?i-j:j-i,//         The absolute difference between `i` and `j`
                   d)          //         And the current integer of the array
               :               //       Else:
                d;             //        Leave the current integer unchanged
  return r;}                   //  Return the result array
```

Comment: @ceilingcat Thanks. Sometimes I'm surprised simple golfs like that are still in my answers. XD Then again, this is an answer from 2017.

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript (ES6), 224 bytes

```
a=>(d=a.split('\n')).slice(e=+d[0]+2).map(f=>{p=e;for(g=(q=(t,s=0)=>d.slice(1,e-1).map(b=c=>c.split(' ')).findIndex((x,y)=>y>=t&x.includes(b(f)[s])))(0);++g;g=q(g))for(l=q(0,1);++l;l=q(l,1))p=p<(u=g>l?g-l:l-g)?p:u;return p})
```

Call with `"6\nnone\napple\norange pear pear\nnone\norange lemon pumpkin\npumpkin lettuce flowers peas\n4\npeas lettuce\napple orange\napple pumpkin\nflowers orange"`

Answer (score 0):

## [Röda](https://github.com/fergusq/roda), 118 bytes

```
{A=[head(parseInteger(pull()))|splitMany|enum]pull n;split|{f={|x|A|[_2]if[x in _1]}f a|{|i|f b|abs i-_}_|min}for a,b}
```

Explanation:

```
{
    A=[
        /* Pull line, convert to integer, and read that many lines */
        head(parseInteger(pull()))|
        /* Split all lines to arrays */
        splitMany|
        /* Enumerate, ie. give each line a number */
        enum
    ]
    /* Discard one line */
    pull n;
    /* Split each following line and push words to the stream */
    split|
    /* For each word a, b in the stream: */
    {
        /* Helper function to find lines that contain x */
        f={|x|A|[_2]if[x in _1]}
        /* Push numbers of lines that contain the first word to the stream */
        f a|
        /* For each line number i */
        {|i|
            /* Push numbers of lines that contain the second word to the stream */
            f b|
            /* Push the difference of two line numbers to the stream */
            abs i-_
        }_|
        /* Push the smallest difference to the stream */
        min
    }for a,b
}
```

No TIO link yet, as the TIO version of Röda is outdated.